# jQuery add first part of div, then add last part of div seperatley

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition, wrapall

I'm trying to wrap the following prices and text together, all in one `div`.

This is what I have:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="thePrices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font class="text colors_text">
          <b>MSRP: <span class="priceis">$90.00</span></b>
        </font><br>
        <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">
                     <font class="text colors_text"><b>Burkett Price:</b></font>
        <span class="priceis">$289<sup>.99</sup></span>
        </font>
        </b><br>
        <a href="a link">A link goes here</a>
        <table>A TABLE WITH STUFF GOES HERE</table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="thePrices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        **
        <div class="pricebox">**
          <font class="text colors_text">
            <b>MSRP: <span class="priceis">$90.00</span></b>
          </font><br>
          <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">
                         <font class="text colors_text"><b>Burkett Price:</b></font>
          <span class="priceis">$289<sup>.99</sup></span>
          </font>
          </b><br> **
        </div>**
        <a href="a link">A link goes here</a>
        <table>A TABLE WITH STUFF GOES HERE</table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This doesn't work but you get the idea of what I'm doing wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.thePrices').find('td').find('font:first').before('<div class="pricebox">');
$('.thePrices').find('.colors_productprice').find('b').after('</div>');
});
```

Perhaps I should be using SLICE?

Comment: could you please explain more about how you want the output to be like ?

Comment: Sure, I just want to WRAP the first font tag and B tag together in a div..in this example with class 'pricebox'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)
*Updated*, to use `.andSelf()` to include `<font/>`

```
$('.thePrices').find('td').children().first().nextUntil('a').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="pricebox"></div>');
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/VkquT/2/)**

Comment: Nice tip, I wasn't aware of `nextUntil` so I didn't think `wrap` could be used for this.

Comment: This now just wraps the Product Price part not the MSRP part in it.

Comment: @Mark This doesn't work correctly for me.  I need it to wrap the first FONT tag also and it is just wrapping the first B tag under the TD?

Comment: @ToddN, see update and fiddle, added `.andSelf()` to include the first element.

Comment: @Mark  this is much closer, but I don't want the A tag in the div.  Is there a way to get it without the A tag wrapping in it?

Comment: @ToddN, i think i got it now, see fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thePrices>tbody>tr>td').children().slice(0,3).wrapAll('<div class="pricebox"></div>');
```

Uses [**slice()**](http://api.jquery.com/slice) to slice the first 3 children before wrapping them, note a `<br>` is a child if you want to wrap the `br` before the `a` change the 3 to 4